# Can we get Accuracy score for each class in multi class in multi classification problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, prediction, metrics

I'm working on a multi class classification problem using onevsrest model with Python, and I want to get the accuracy score for each class, for example, class1 : accuracy 80%, class2 : accuracy 88%, class3 : accuracy 90%, I only get the accuracy of the entire model, how can I get it for each class ?

Comment: Plot the confusion matrix, then you can see for each class what the number of predictions are and work out the percentage from that. This question has also been answered here which may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770376/scikit-learn-get-accuracy-scores-for-each-class